# How to generate Angular4 javascript es6 scaffold app

Tags: angular

Is there any possibility to easy generate Angular 4 (or Angular 2) app that uses ES6 JavaScript instead of TypeScript? I maybe unaware and maybe it works out of the box, but as I've checked angular-cli and angular documentation there's no information how it's possible.

Comment: `ng new --styleExt scss --routing [folderName]`

Comment: I don't think that works, certainly not out of the box. I have the latest CLI installed (per their update directions). I ran the above command, it generates: "The option '--styleExt' is not registered with the new command..."thefolder" did not match any files, so no file updates will be made."

Comment: Yeah the effect of that command is is creates a directory called SCSS, with a node_modules folder, and nothing in it. Absolute latest and greatest CLI (even gives the deprecation warning about the soon-to-come forwardning change in package name etc).

Comment: here is  angular2 ES6 starter https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-babel-esnext-starter, but as far as i can see it not updated to angular4 version yet... but may it is not big deal to upgrade..

Comment: I also publish an angular seed, ES6 and Babel. I will see if I can just swap out angular 4 right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This uses Ang4, Babel, WebPack 2, has all the updated related packages (required for WP2 etc.) etc. Follow the instructions in README.md (basically, pull it down, run "npm install", then "npm run serve", which fires up the webpack dev server/watcher). Router config and all that set up, couple of scrap components in there and whatnot as basic samples.

Probably the most interesting thing is the package.json file. Anybody that knows Angular2 from scratch could just grab that.

Not thoroughly tested, but seems to just work. Post if anything looks broken and I try to fix.

https://github.com/tcoz/ang2-babel-webpack/tree/angular4

Answer (score 0):

I built a scaffolding tool. You can download it from npm.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-scaffolder

You can create es6 angular, react and angular 1 scaffolds from cli

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 1 button scaffolding engine for React on ASP.NET Core.  Very easy to use, very complete (will generate your entire application from your model), and customizable, i.e. you can modify templates... http://bssdev.biz/DevTools/React-Turbo-Scaffolding-Free-Download